# Debian 12 and NTFS permissions

Tags: permissions, ntfs, fstab

Back in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I could copy to and from NTFS partitions without problems. Practically all apps had access to everything. Then there was an accident that made me not just upgrade to 22 but having to reinstall it completely. Now programs were having troubles saving to the NTFS partition, most notably Double Commander needed to ask for root to complete a copy. I had to go to something like Software Center and give permission to each and every app. Big problem when it comes to programs that don't get registered (properly) like Steam (which could not update Gmod anymore because its resources were symlinked to the NTFS parts).

I then decided to replace Ubuntu with Debian 12 because of lightweightedness, however been getting the same problem with DC so not sure if I should get Steam going again just yet. This is what my `fstab` looks like.

```
# Win Parts
# /dev/sda2 C:\
UUID=A03A04FA3A04CF6A /media/sda2     ntfs    user,exec,auto,umask=0  0       0
# /dev/sda8 E:\
UUID=078A40594387992A /media/sda8     ntfs    user,exec,auto,umask=0  0       0
# /dev/sdb7 H:\
UUID=18F7C0FB55E53731 /media/sdb7     ntfs    user,exec,auto,umask=0  0       0
```

Basically the exact same options as waaay back in Ubuntu 14 (just `/dev/` except for `UUID`). What has changed?

Comment: See an example of an fstab entry is `/dev/sda5 /media/ntfs ntfs-3g exec,permissions,auto 0 0` in the post [Mount NTFS partition at startup, with non-root user as owner](https://askubuntu.com/a/92866/963426).

Comment: @harrymc After doing this, suddenly I did not have access to some folders. They were marked as `drwx------` or `dr-xr-xr-x`. I then did a full `chmod -R 777` before I could traverse and DC did not complain on a copy.

Comment: See the rest of the answer as regarding `chown`. If some sub-folders are still inaccessible, add more information to your post about their ownership and permissions.